# how to search an element in a JTable java?

Tags: java, swing, search, jtable

I have made a JTable in java.
I can do everything except search an element in my table.
I want to work a input dialog so this is what I have at this moment:

```
btnSearch = new JButton("Search");
    btnSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {    
            String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Wat wil je zoeken?");
        }
    });
    add(btnSearch);
```

I thought to do it with a for loop.
but I don't know how.
Can someone help me pls?

Comment: To create the jtable, you will have used the datatableModel. In that you can perform the search.

Answer (score 58):

You probably want to use a `RowFilter` to filter the search results. Below is an example using a `RowFilter` and a `DocumentListener`. When the user types, the rows are filter dynamically.

See [**RowFilter**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?javax/swing/RowFilter.html) api and [**DocumentListener**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html) api. If you don't like the dynamic filtering, you could just stick with the button, or you can add an `ActionListener` to the the `JTextField`, so when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed, the filter will process. The code you would put in the listener call back (`actionPerformed`) would just be

```
  String text = jtfFilter.getText();
  if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
     rowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
  } else {
     rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
  }
```

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class TestTableSortFilter extends JPanel {

    private String[] columnNames
            = {"Country", "Capital", "Population in Millions", "Democracy"};

    private Object[][] data = {
        {"USA", "Washington DC", 280, true},
        {"Canada", "Ottawa", 32, true},
        {"United Kingdom", "London", 60, true},
        {"Germany", "Berlin", 83, true},
        {"France", "Paris", 60, true},
        {"Norway", "Oslo", 4.5, true},
        {"India", "New Delhi", 1046, true}
    };

    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    private JTable jTable = new JTable(model);

    private TableRowSorter<TableModel> rowSorter
            = new TableRowSorter<>(jTable.getModel());

    private JTextField jtfFilter = new JTextField();
    private JButton jbtFilter = new JButton("Filter");

    public TestTableSortFilter() {
        jTable.setRowSorter(rowSorter);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(new JLabel("Specify a word to match:"),
                BorderLayout.WEST);
        panel.add(jtfFilter, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(new JScrollPane(jTable), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        jtfFilter.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                String text = jtfFilter.getText();

                if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
                    rowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
                } else {
                    rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                String text = jtfFilter.getText();

                if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
                    rowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
                } else {
                    rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
               JFrame frame = new JFrame("Row Filter");
               frame.add(new TestTableSortFilter());
               frame.pack();
               frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
               frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
               frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Helped a lot. U deserve more than a **Upvote**. Cheers

Comment: Thanks! Excellent example and easy to use!

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect for me

Answer (score 5):

The model of a JTable is where the data is held, by searching it you should be able to check if it contains what you want
:

```
for(int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++){//For each row
    for(int j = 0; j < table.getColumnCount(); j++){//For each column in that row
        if(table.getModel().getValueAt(i, j).equals("STRING_TO_SEARCH")){//Search the model
            System.out.println(table.getModel().getValueAt(i, j));//Print if found string
        }
    }//For loop inner
}//For loop outer
```

Good luck!

Comment: then for why reason is RowFilter there

Comment: this is the good example because the user ask for searching and not for filtering. When you want to search for a record from a jtable you want that record to be automatically selected and the other rows of the table to be visible. When you filter the jtable the only visible rows are the rows which contains the input keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of searching text from `JTable` entered in `JTextField`

Source : [Filter table by the text in a TextField](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/FiltertablebythetextinaTextField.htm)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class RegexTable {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Regexing JTable");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Object rows[][] = { { "A", "About", 44.36 }, { "B", "Boy", 44.84 }, { "C", "Cat", 463.63 },
        { "D", "Day", 27.14 }, { "E", "Eat", 44.57 }, { "F", "Fail", 23.15 },
        { "G", "Good", 4.40 }, { "H", "Hot", 24.96 }, { "I", "Ivey", 5.45 },
        { "J", "Jack", 49.54 }, { "K", "Kids", 280.00 } };
    String columns[] = { "Symbol", "Name", "Price" };
    TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(rows, columns) {
      public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
        Class returnValue;
        if ((column >= 0) && (column < getColumnCount())) {
          returnValue = getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
        } else {
          returnValue = Object.class;
        }
        return returnValue;
      }
    };

    final JTable table = new JTable(model);
    final TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
    table.setRowSorter(sorter);
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
    frame.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Filter");
    panel.add(label, BorderLayout.WEST);
    final JTextField filterText = new JTextField("A");
    panel.add(filterText, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    JButton button = new JButton("Filter");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String text = filterText.getText();
        if (text.length() == 0) {
          sorter.setRowFilter(null);
        } else {
          sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(text));
        }
      }
    });
    frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.setSize(300, 250);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a note
If you  getValueAt after sorting this will result the ORIGINAL row index. (which will be the wrong object)
In that case you can use : [JTable API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel-int-)

```
table.convertRowIndexToModel (int indexAfterSorting) ;
```

This will Translate the sorted Row index into the original Row